# Is there an implementation for move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction for ros2?

Tags: ros, simpleactionclient, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. So, I migrating my project from Noetic to Foxy and I have there code, that looks like this

---

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
```

---

And I have problems with understanding, how it should look on Foxy. There are no MoveBaseAction.h header for ros2, or at least I could't find it. I appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407759/is-there-an-implementation-for-move_base_msgs::movebaseaction-for-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nadavis](https://answers.ros.org/users/139792/nadavis/) on 2023-06-13**:
Hi, i have the same issue, did you find a solution?

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2023-07-13**:
Hi. Sorry to disapoint, but no. I marked Nav2 as right answer because it is more or less what I was looking for, but, in the end, we simply using code that does not involve actionlib for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, when using ROS2 you probably want to rely on `Nav2`(https://navigation.ros.org/). This is the "successor" of the ROS Navigation stack we had for ROS1.

Check [ros1-to-ros2](https://navigation.ros.org/about/ros1_comparison.html#ros1-comparison) for further information about changes in the navigation stack when moving from ros1 to ros2.

---

Originally posted by [francocipollone](https://answers.ros.org/users/118643/francocipollone/) with karma: 16 on 2022-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-13**:
Thanks, I check it and I think, that it is what I need